Is "fall by the wayside" a common idiom among native speakers? Do I use it correctly in the sentence below?
I've learned the idiom "fall by the wayside" and its meaning is useful. However, there are a lot of idioms that have useful meanings but fell by the wayside tens of years ago. English learners should steer clear of them if they don't want to sound funny.
So, is it still in common use? Is it okay to use the idiom like this:

But then came the Internet explosion in my country and reading books fell by the wayside for me.


Yes, fall by the wayside is used commonly. Your example is fine.

In fact your dry humour shows you know exactly how to use this idiom!

Thank you both for your confirmation. One more question and I think this is actually more important: Is there any way for English learners to know if an idiom has fallen out of use?

I would be so happy if there's a source for this.

I think your first usage "fell by the wayside tens of years ago" was correct. Using the phrase in a general sense. The second one "fell by the wayside for me", sounds less idiomatic, somehow or other. To check current usage: Google's ngram. Also, Linguee is interesting.

If you want to know if it's out of use, check dictionaries, search the web, and see how and where it's used - if it's in social media or blogs it's more likely to be current than in journalism. And don't use long, elaborate idioms in mundane situations.

“Fell by the wayside” is more used for an act that is less common among a group of people.
